# How to use rimraf from cli to delete build folder but not remove the "build" folder itself

Tags: node.js, fs, package.json, rm

I want to delete the build folder for my repo. All contents inside it. But I need to keep the build folder. Essentially clean everything inside the folder but remove it.

Currently I am using "rimraf build" in package.json scripts. But it removes the build folder as well.

How do i use rimraf ( or any other utility ) to remove the contents of a folder but not the folder itself?

Comment: `rimraf build  && mkdir -p build` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rimraf <dirname>/*` should delete all files but not the parent folder.

So, `rimraf build/*` should work for your case/

Comment: `rimraf <path>/*`

Comment: excellent. It works.. I should have tried with /* .. But thanks for your response. Big help to my project

Comment: Everything is removed, except ".clasp.json". Should i pass some extra arguments for full cleanup?

Answer (score 3):

For `rimraf@5` you need to pass `--glob` to the command to get it to recognize the asterisk:

```
rimraf build/* --glob
```